# Why does a disk busy spike happen between finishing of a job and shutting down Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I detected an unexpected disk IO (DISKBUSY spike) after all my spark tasks 
finished but spark context has not stopped -- as shown in figure case 2 at 
`21:56:47`. Could anyone help explain it and give suggestions on how to avoid 
or postpone it? Or does spark context have some periodical async IO 
activities that might lead to the spikes? Thanks!

Given an example of running a SparkSQL batch job in two cases. In the first 
one, I execute the sql workload, and stop spark context immediately after 
`.show()` action finishes. In the second case, I add a 1-minute sleep after 
`.show()` by using `Thread.sleep(60000)`, then stop the spark context. The result shows that the time costs for executing the sql workload in two cases are similar, but **there is an unexpected DISKBUSY spike on the disk** who is doing local storage for shuffle write in the second case. See the spike in the figure of case 2.

Here are more details.

The system setup

- Spark 2.3.1, Hadoop 2.9.1, Hive 2.3.4 for metadata storage.
- One master and two worker nodes (worker1 and worker2). Each node has enough available resources 
  (32 cores, 750G memory and 8 8-T disks from disk1 to disk8).
- The HDFS is deployed on disk8; the disk1 is used for the spark shuffle writing local storage.
- I use Yarn as cluster management.
- I use a system monitor tool "nmon" to detect the disk activities.
- There is no other big application running in the backend.
- I use `yarn client` mode when submitting my code. I use 8 executors each having 4 cores and 8GB memory.
- To note, I put the HDFS and Yarn local file on two different disks -- `yarn_local` directory is on each worker's disk1 and HDFS is deployed on disk8s of two worker nodes. Each disk has `8T`. So the activities for HDFS and local disk can be distinguished.

Here is my current analysis

1. It is not caused by the disk itself and other background processes. I tried disk2, disk3, disk4, and disk8 for yarn local storage for testing if the spike is related to the program and it shows the same spikes every time I executed the case 2.
2. The spike is caused by Spark itself. I tried the standalone deploy mode and the spike still exists (with no Yarn).
3. It might be relevant to the shuffling. The total shuffle write size of my target batch job is close to `2GB`. I also tried different workload with its shuffle writing size close to `1MB`, `250MB` and `1GB`. The DISKBUSY becomes negligible for the batch job with shuffling write size `1MB` and becomes up to `80%` for the batch job with the total shuffling write size `250MB`.
4. The size of the local storage file is traced. When disk spike appears, disk writing is detected but the disk size does not increase. Therefore, (1) it might not relevant to disk cache clean (2) it might be some disk swapping happening (not too sure).

According to my analysis currently, I suspect that it should be caused by something I am not familiar -- such as some spark async behavior on disks. Could anyone help explain it? Thanks!

Here is the first case.
[image: Case 1: without sleep]

Here is the second case.
[image: Case 2: with 60 seconds sleep]

To be more clear in the figure, the `worker1 node local` stands for the disk1 in worker1, `the worker2 local` stands for the disk1 in worker2; the `worker1 node dfs` stands for the disk8 in worker1 and the `worker2 node dfs` stands for the disk8 in worker2, where HDFS locates. The left y-axis is the diskbusy (from 0% to 100%) detected by `nmon` and the right y-axis is the size of the directory for hdfs in disk8 (which we can just ignore for this problem).

Here is my code.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Q16 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val db = s"bigbench_sf_100"

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    spark.sql(s"use $db")

    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT w_state, i_item_id,
         |  SUM(
         |    CASE WHEN (unix_timestamp(d_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') < unix_timestamp('2001-03-16','yyyy-MM-dd'))
         |    THEN ws_sales_price - COALESCE(wr_refunded_cash,0)
         |    ELSE 0.0 END
         |  ) AS sales_before,
         |  SUM(
         |    CASE WHEN (unix_timestamp(d_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= unix_timestamp('2001-03-16','yyyy-MM-dd'))
         |    THEN ws_sales_price - COALESCE(wr_refunded_cash,0)
         |    ELSE 0.0 END
         |  ) AS sales_after
         |FROM (
         |  SELECT *
         |  FROM web_sales ws
         |  LEFT OUTER JOIN web_returns wr ON (ws.ws_order_number = wr.wr_order_number
         |    AND ws.ws_item_sk = wr.wr_item_sk)
         |) a1
         |JOIN item i ON a1.ws_item_sk = i.i_item_sk
         |JOIN warehouse w ON a1.ws_warehouse_sk = w.w_warehouse_sk
         |JOIN date_dim d ON a1.ws_sold_date_sk = d.d_date_sk
         |AND unix_timestamp(d.d_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >= unix_timestamp('2001-03-16', 'yyyy-MM-dd') - 30*24*60*60 --subtract 30 days in seconds
         |AND unix_timestamp(d.d_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') <= unix_timestamp('2001-03-16', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 30*24*60*60 --add 30 days in seconds
         |GROUP BY w_state,i_item_id
         |--original was ORDER BY w_state,i_item_id , but CLUSTER BY is hives cluster scale counter part
         |ORDER BY w_state,i_item_id
         |LIMIT 100
       """.stripMargin).show
    val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()

//    For case 2
//    Thread.sleep(60 * 1000)

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the reason for the unexpected IO activity.

This is the file system buffer cache behavior. In general, when a process writes to a file, the data is not written to disk immediately and instead it is written to a cache in memory. This cache is maintained by the OS/file system as a performance optimization since it allows write requests to return after writing to memory and not wait for slow I/Os to complete. This dirty data is periodically flushed to disk in the background by the OS.

So basically, the disk activities (flushing) are not avoidable unless the file pages are deleted when cached in the disk buffer (in case 1).

You can force all dirty data to be written out immediately by using a Linux system command `sync`.